# Replace the Row Values with Matching row values with column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Data frame looks below foramt

```
fdf = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'john', 'john': np.nan, 'mac': np.nan,'val':22}, {'name': 'mac', 'john': np.nan, 'mac': np.nan,'val':55}], columns=["name", "john", "mac",'val'])


fdf
Out[466]: 
   name  john  mac  val
0  john   NaN  NaN   22
1   mac   NaN  NaN   55
```

I want to replace the NaN values with matching row value with respect column name

Output

```
fdf
Out[466]: 
   name  john  mac  val
0  john   22   NaN   22
1   mac   NaN  55    55
```

**`Here 1st row of name column value is john and corresponding val column value is 22 , so replace the value in matching column name john.`**

Any help appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`df.combine_first()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)/[**`df.update()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) after [**`unstack()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s=fdf.set_index('name',append=True)['val'].unstack()
fdf = fdf.combine_first(s).reindex(columns=fdf.columns) #preferred for updating NaN
#or update:-> fdf.update(s)
```

---

```
   name  john   mac  val
0  john  22.0   NaN   22
1   mac   NaN  55.0   55
```