# Matching the column values to the row values and write in the new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

My first dataframe looks like this:

df1:

```
ID      Name    Result
ABC1    John     A
ABC1    Mac      B
ABC1    Kat      C
DEF1    John     D
DEF1    Mac      E
DEF1    Kat      F
XYZ1    John     G
XYZ1    Mac      H
XYZ1    Kat      I
```

df2:

```
ID      John    Mac    Kat
ABC1    22      33     11
DEF1    10      12     2
XYZ2    11      12     36
```

The result df3: (It should match the ID and name of df1 with the ID and names (John, Mac and Kat) with the column of df2 and then give their respective values.

```
ID      Name    Result  Value
ABC1    John    A       22
ABC1    Mac     B       33
ABC1    Kat     C       11
DEF1    John    D       10
DEF1    Mac     E       12
DEF1    Kat     F        2
XYZ1    John    G        0
XYZ1    Mac     H        0
XYZ1    Kat     I        0
```

There are multiple questions:

[Use column headers to find matching value and get value in matching column for the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471131/use-column-headers-to-find-matching-value-and-get-value-in-matching-column-for-t)

[Replace the Row Values with Matching row values with column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092403/replace-the-row-values-with-matching-row-values-with-column-names)

But it works only with one dataframe so I thought to merge the dataframes but doens't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df1.join(df2.set_index('ID').stack().rename('Value'), on=['ID','Name'])
         .fillna({'Value':0}))
```

Or [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = (df1.merge(df2.melt('ID', var_name='Name', value_name='Value'), 
                on=['ID','Name'], how='left')
         .fillna({'Value':0}))
```

---

```
print (df)
     ID  Name Result  Value
0  ABC1  John      A   22.0
1  ABC1   Mac      B   33.0
2  ABC1   Kat      C   11.0
3  DEF1  John      D   10.0
4  DEF1   Mac      E   12.0
5  DEF1   Kat      F    2.0
6  XYZ1  John      G    0.0
7  XYZ1   Mac      H    0.0
8  XYZ1   Kat      I    0.0
```